# Safari does not show images, but FireFox does

Tags: html, css, image, safari

I have a website that I am working on: http://keramed.com

in FireFox on my Mac the image on the main page shows up. (The Endoshield DSEK Graft Injector)

Now check in Safari and the image does not show up.

I have tried taking the original .PSD and saving it as a .jpg or .png and it does not matter.

I have commented out all stylesheets and this still does not solve it. The rest of my images are showing up, just not thing one.

I just dont understand I am stumped.

EDIT:> Photoshop says it is an RGB 8-bit image.

Comment: It's very hard to say definitively what the source of the problem is, because your markup doesn't conform to HTML 4.01 Strict, which your document claims to be in its DOCTYPE. Try fixing the problems found by the W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image isn't showing up in Chromium either. However, taking out the image width and height specified on the image element as percentages has fixed the problem. It is better to avoid using percentages as widths/heights for images as they may not render as well as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not the image, as safari can render it, see: http://keramed.com/images/mainimage2.jpg

You are having over-flow: hidden, somewhere and I suspect it's that. Or if you are using js to change the display of the image from `none` to be shown, that might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem which I solved changing height/width in pixels rather than percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for browsers do not display the image — 'content' parameter in stylesheets that are associated with the image.

For example, I faced with the same problem some time ago and it happened because into the stylesheet the class used for the image had 'content' parameter.

```
.image_class {
    ...
    content: ''
}
```